# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.partitions in Cloudera CDH 5.5.0 VM, Spark 2.4.7, JDK1.8.0_181

Tags: apache-spark-sql, py4j

I am learning to use Spark on a personal computer with hardware capable of running Hadoop. Here's the config:

> Cloudera CDH 5.5.0 w/ Cloudera Quickstart, Spark 2.4.7, JDK1.8.0_181, Hadoop 2.6.0, Python 3.6.9.

When running a Python script (copied from a Udemy video on YouTube), I ran into and fixed several errors, but I could not find any solution for the following one:

> java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs: /user/cloudera / Spark / ml - 100 k / u.data

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/cloudera/Spark/LowestRatedMovieDataFrame.py", line 75, in < module >
  movieDataset = spark.createDataFrame(movies)

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 746, in createDataFrame

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 390, in _createFromRDD

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 361, in _inferSchema

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1378, in first

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1327, in take

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2517, in getNumPartitions

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco

File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred
while calling o27.partitions.: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs: /user/cloudera / Spark / ml - 100 k / u.data
```